# Remove request from nginx error logs

Tags: security, logging, nginx

How can we remove request url being logged in nginx error logs. For example it looks something like:

2015/09/01 15:26:03 [error] 30547#0: *208725 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.123.50.44, server: test.example.com, request: "GET /v1.3/status.json?...."

is it possible to drop request since it can have PII from the log(if present) so it looks something like:

2015/09/01 15:26:03 [error] 30547#0: *208725 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.123.50.44, server: test.example.com

I was able to configure access logs but couldn't find a way to customize error logs.

Edit:
Is there a way to stop logging only upstream errors?

Comment: Not a good idea to have PII in the URL at all, because it will also be logged by proxy logs, browser history and could escape in the `referer` header. If this is solely for a server side API though, then it is less risky. If you can alter your application so it POSTs the data instead, that would be a better bet.

Comment: Thanks @SilverlightFox for the suggestion.

Comment: @SilverlightFox is there a way to ignore logging only upstream errors in error logs ?